# Vectors and unit vector in programming

Tags: vector-spaces

First, my math is horrible, that is why I am brushing up at Khan. I have been watching and learning about vectors by the most awesome Sal Khan at Khan academy. My question is more of a general one regarding representing 3D entities on something like a CAD program. Entities like planes, vectors, etc.

All of what Sal does is based with the origin as the starting point of the vector. He is careful to point out that a vector can start at any coordinate though. I suspect that this is to make things much simpler and explain the properties.

My question is this...when a person is representing and doing math in programming (let's say a line that goes from 2,2,2 -> 5,5,5) of a vector does one transform the vector to (0,0), do the math and then transform the result back to it's original position or is something done to it "in place"?

Answer (score 0):

No, not necessarily. When we consider the vector you stated then we essentially have an arrow with a specific length and specific direction. We can freely move it about wherever we like (as long as we don't do any rotation, stretching, etc...) So, we just think about it however is most convenient. 
When dealing with things in the programming sense: you would likely be using vectors in a fairly geometric context and so we would want to leave them wherever we "found" them essentially. Otherwise, we are probably doing more "pure" mathematical operations which don't care where the vector originated from.